# Publishing paid application on Android market

Tags: android, google-play

I need to publish a paid Android application. This means that the application is not free for download, payment is required before the user can download.

Can anyone help with the steps that I need to follow to achieve this?

Comment: This question has really nothing to ask and if you simply search on Google or simply read faqs on the android official site then you can easily get answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Android's official site has all the explanations.](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the [Android Market help](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html) on the topic? It seems pretty exhaustive...

If you have any specific issues, it would help if you published them here to get the right answer.

If you are not eligible for a Google Merchant Account, you might consider hiring a [proxy company](http://www.androidpublisher.com/).